# Using Apache ProxyPass or Mod_jk with Tomcat when there are special characters in the URL path

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, proxy

I am struggling with a problem in ProxyPass. I have tried using Apache and Nginx to setup Proxypass with tomcat. Everything is fine, apart from when there is any character in the URL. 
I don't know whether it is a bug in Apache or what, the request URI I am getting in my program from Apache as proxy is different from using Tomcat without proxy. I am using `"request.getRequestURI()"` in Java Servlet. 
For example, if the URL is

```
/movies/logs, logs
```

Use Apache or Nginx setup ProxyPass or Mod_jk I got:

```
/movies/logs,%20logs
```

If I use Tomcat directly, I got:

```
/movies/logs%2C%20logs
```

Ideally, I want the URL to be the same one as I received in Tomcat. Can someone help me fix the problem?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: A URL shouldn't contain spaces, it should contain %20 escapes, and the same for the others. The real problem here is the client.

Answer (score 1):

By default Apache canonicalises URL's before passing them further, and apparently tomcat alone does it differently. To prevent mod_proxy from modifying your URL's, add [*nocanon*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) keyword to ProxyPass directive.

Note, that both spaces and commas are considered to be unsafe in [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) and should not be used unescaped.